# g:formatDate as value on g:textField

Tags: jquery, grails, datetimepicker

I have this `.gsp` file which uses the `JQuery.datetimepicker()` to a particular `<g:textField >`. When the `<g:form>` of the `<g:textField>` is submitted, I have to convert from `java.lang.String` to `java.util.Date` following the steps provided by [RoseIndia](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-conversion/StringToDate.shtml) to match with the property of the pertaining domain of the concerned controller.

The problem is having to display the `java.util.Date` property of the domain back to `java.lang.String` to be displayed in the `<g:textField>` following to format of `JQuery.datetimepicker()`. I have tried to use `<g:formateDate>` which worked but I have to display the result back to the `<g:textField>` for me to use the `JQuery.datetimepicker()` to that particular field.

The Javascript:

```
$("#datetime").datetimepicker({
  timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
```

In the body:

```
<!-- Error here which return a GrailsTagException -->
<% println ${formatDate(format:"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", date:"model?.createdDate")} %>
<g:formatDate format="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" date="${model?.createdDate}"/>
<g:textField name="dateReported" id="datetime" value="${model?.createdDate}"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be misreading your issue but can't you do:

`<g:textField name="dateReported" value="${formatDate(format:"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", date:model?.createdDate)}"/>`.

Note the removal of the quotes around "model?.createdDate" as it will eval this as a string not a reference to the date itself.  Also you don't need the id the taglib will create this for you with the same name as the "name" attribute.